# Disable event handler in Visual Studio MFC based application

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc

I am working on a project. It has GUI and i add Start button on it , which is handled by some function. and after clicking on start ,that Gui shows the output. I want to disable that handler function. Whenever i debug that project, start button should automatically started and GUI shows the output.

This is the code of that handler. What should i change or move that function ?

```
          void CServerSocketDlg::OnBtnStart() 
             {
            UpdateData();

            StartX();
             }
```

Need your suggestion. Thanks

Comment: Please improve your question.

Comment: Why do you want to DISABLE the event handler. It sounds more like you want to automatically call the event handler?

Comment: yes. automatically call the event handler .. it means i dont need to press Start button. it should be automatically executed.

Answer (score 1):

So add something like this in an appropriate location. For example, in a dialog, you could put it in `OnInitDialog`:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
if(IsDebuggerPresent())
{
    /* code here to automatically do whatever you need when a debugger is attached */
}
#endif
```

This code will only be compiled in the "Debug" versions of the application and will execute only if the application is running under the debugger.

Comment: Adding to Nik's answer: Inside the _DEBUG call, you can send a WM_LBUTTONDOWN and an WM_LBUTTONUP message to your window to simulate a click